# How To return comma delimited values from 3 joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Joining these tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppSettings]
(
    [AppSettingId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [EntryId] [INT] NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entry]
(
    [EntryId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [INT] NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons]
(
    [PersonId] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [AddressId] INT NULL,
);
```

Given AppSettings' unique value is `ClientId` and that there is a one-to-many relationship between `AppSettings` and `Entry`.

One `AppSettings` with a unique `ClientId` can have multiple `Entry` records.

How do I return a comma delimited `Persons.EmailAddress` grouped by `AppSettings.ClientId`?

I've only manage to figure out to use String_agg to delimit email but group by is limiting me

Comment: Use `STRING_AGG`. You didn't specify which version you use. `STRING_AGG` is available in all versions still in mainstream support. There are several duplicate questions that show how to do this in older versions.

Comment: I already know to use string_agg im struggling with grouping it with clientid.

Comment: Then show us your attempts and explain why it isn't working, @ByronScott .

Comment: We can't guess what you want to do, or what the problem is. Did you use `GROUP BY ClientID` in your query? Have you joined the three tables?